# Bold authors' names in reference list

Tags: bibliographies, bold, apa-style, author

I try to make the names of authors bold in my bibliography, and keep them normal (unbold) in the document body `\cite{Smith2005Latex}`. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
\author{Add Author name here} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\let\runauthor\@author
\makeatother
\fancyhead{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chead{\runauthor}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot{}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[vertfit]{breakurl}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\MyComment}[1]{
    { {\# #1}}
}

\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
     \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
     \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar}{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
     \NAT@date}}
  {\@citea\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
   \NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}}{}{}

\patchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
     \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
     \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi}%
       {\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
     \NAT@date}}
  {\@citea\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
   \NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}}
  {}{}

\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt} % array table padding
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newcommand{\myscalebox}[1]{\scalebox{0.87}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\olds}[1]{\oldstylenums{#1}}
 \newcommand{\oldsb}[1]{{\bfseries\olds{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\rnote}[1]{\stepcounter{ncomm}%
 \vbox to0pt{\vss\llap{\tiny\oldsb{\arabic{ncomm}}}\vskip6pt}%
 \marginpar{\tiny\bf\raggedright%
 {\oldsb{\arabic{ncomm}}}.\hskip0.5em#1}}
 \newcounter{ncomm}
\newcommand\pnote[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\poldnote[1]{\emph{\textcolor{black}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\easychair}{\textsf{easychair}}
\newcommand{\miktex}{MiK{\TeX}}
\newcommand{\texniccenter}{{\TeX}nicCenter}
\newcommand{\makefile}{\texttt{Makefile}}
\newcommand{\latexeditor}{LEd}
\newcommand{\maxd}{\ensuremath{\textit{D}_{\textit{Max}}}}
\newcommand{\mind}{\ensuremath{\textit{D}_{\textit{Min}}}}
\newcommand{\SD}{\ensuremath{\textit ST }}
\newcommand{\RR}{\ensuremath{\textit{RR}}}
\newcommand{\RP}{\ensuremath{\textit{RP}}}
\newcommand{\MP}{\ensuremath{\textit{MP}}}
\newcommand{\NR}{\ensuremath{\textit{NR}}}
\newcommand{\BR}{\ensuremath{\textit{BR}}}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\vspace*{-.2cm}\paragraph*{#1}}


\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\diag[4]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{p{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=#1]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep-\pgflinewidth},
        minimum  height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight-\pgflinewidth] (box) {};
  \draw[line cap=round] (box.north west) -- (box.south east);
  \node[anchor=south west] at (box.south west) {#3};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (box.north east) {#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

 \usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@combinedblfloats{\box\@outputbox}{\unvbox\@outputbox}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand patch failed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bibliography{x}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

And the bib file `x.bib`:

```
@incollection{Smith2005Latex,
  title={ \uppercase{L}atex  \uppercase{E}xample },
  author={ X. Smith and Y.  Smeeth and Z. smithh   },
  booktitle={Managment System},
  editor={Skil K.},
  pages={100--200},
  year={2005},
  publisher="Springer",
}
```

Comment: The solution will depend on the bibliography style (argument to `\bibliographystyle`) you use as well as (possibly) other bibliography- and citation-related packages you load (`natbib`, `cite`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...). So please tell us more about your current set-up in form of a small, yet compilable example document.